# Apache freemarker template assign and compare values

Tags: freemarker

I am assigning value to a variable i_type using below assign statement.

```
<#assign i_type>  
<#if x.has("type")>
    <#if x.type == "ABC">"ABC"<#else>"${x.type?lower_case}"</#if>
<#else>"pqr"</#if>
</#assign>
```

Then I want to assign a variable in ftl conversion as:

```
"final_type" : <#if i_type?has_content && i_type == "pqr">1<#else>0</#if>
```

But value of final_type is always coming out to be 0 in all cases.
I explicitly printed value of i_type and even though it was "pqr" but condition is always coming out to be false.

what should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the original example doesn't work is that you have quotation marks in `<#else>"pqr"</#if>`, and on the other similar places. That way the captured value itself will contain the quotation marks, because the nested content of FreeMarker directives is not expressions, instead it's just like top-level template content. So just write `<#else>pqr</#if>`.

Anyway, a better way to write what you did is this:

```
<#assign i_type =
   x.has("type")?then(
     (x.type == "ABC")?then(x.type, x.type?lower_case),
     "pqr"
   )
>
```

You also don't need the `i_type?has_content` condition in the second piece of code, since something is always assigned to `i_type`. (But even if in reality it isn't, you can write `i_type!` to default a missing value to `""`.) So that can be written like this:

```
"final_type" : ${(i_type == "pqr")?then("1", "0")}
```

Comment: When an answer worked, please accept it too (green check mark).

Answer (score 0):

Once I used

```
"final_type" : <#if i_type?has_content && i_type?eval == "pqr">1<#else>0</#if>
```

it worked fine.

Comment: Don't do that. You call `?eval` just to remove quotation marks that you have added yourself. You can just not add them instead.